# Adding no_story=true when uploading photo causes Graph API to fail with exception

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload

I want to upload an image with no_story by using official FB php lib.

the code looks like this:

```
    $payload = [
        'message' => 'Hello world!',
        'source' =>new \CURLFile($path, 'image/jpeg','test.jpg'),
        'no_story' => true
    ];

    $post = (
        new FacebookRequest(
            $mySession, 'POST', '/me/photos', $payload
        ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

And each time i attempt to upload i get a `FacebookServerException` with message `An unknown error has occurred` message.

It starts to work as soon as I remove `'no_story' => true` from payload.

What am I doing wrong?

To be more precise, server response is `"{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}"`

Comment: The same problem with Android SDK. Did You find any solution?

Comment: No, for now I just post photos without it. BTW it also doesn't work at FB API Explorer.